# 数値リストの値を集計する

Tags: python

1. 5、3、12、8、2の要素からなるリストを作成する
2. 集計結果を記録する変数totalに0を代入する
3. for文を使ってリストの要素を1つずつtotalに加える
4. totalの値を表示する

以上の4つのプロセスをクリアしたいのですが途中でどうしたらよいかわからなくなってしまいました。教えていただけると嬉しいです。

```
numbers = [5, 3, 12, 8, 2]
total = 0
for tatal :
    print(total)
```

実行結果は30となります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for ループの使い方ですね。

```
numbers = [5, 3, 12, 8, 2]
total = 0
for number in numbers:
    total += number
print(total)
```

number には、numbers の要素が一回のループ毎に一つずつ抜き出されて使われます。
それが total に積算されることになるわけです。